# python threading in a loop

Tags: python, multithreading, loops

I have a project that requires a bunch of large matrices, which are stored in ~200 MB files, to be cross-correlated (i.e. FFT * conj(FFT)) with each other.  The number of files is such that I can't just load them all up and then do my processing.  On the other hand, reading in each file as I need it is slower than I'd like.

what I have so far is something like:

```
result=0
for i in xrange(N_files):
    f1 = file_reader(file_list[i])

    ############################################################################
    # here I want to have file_reader go start reading the next file I'll need #
    ############################################################################

    in_place_processing(f1)
    for j in xrange(i+1,N_files):
        f2 = file_reader(file_list[j])

        ##################################################################
        # here I want to have file_reader go start reading the next file #
        ##################################################################

        in_place_processing(f2)
        result += processing_function(f1,f2)
```

So basically, I just want to have two threads that will each read a file, give it to me when I ask for it (or as soon as it's done after I ask for it), and then go start reading the next file for when I ask for it.  The object the file_reader returns is rather large and complicated, so I'm not sure if multiprocessing is the way to go here...

I've read about threading and queues but can't seem to figure out the part where I ask the thread to go read the file and can proceed with the program while it does.  I don't want the threads to simply go about their business in the background -- am I missing a detail here, or is threading not the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of using the `multiprocessing` module that will spawn off child processes to call your `file_reader` method and queue up their results.  The queue should block when full, so you can control the number of read ahead's you'd like to perform with the `QUEUE_SIZE` constant.

This utilizes a standard Producer/Consumer model of multiprocess communication, with the child processes act as Producers, with the main thread being the Consumer.  The `join` method call in the class destructor ensures the child process resources are cleaned up properly.  There are some print statements interspersed for demonstration purposes.

Additionally, I added the ability for the QueuedFileReader class to offload work to a worker thread or run in the main thread, rather than using a child process, for comparison.  This is done by specifying the mode parameter at class initialization to `MODE_THREADS` or `MODE_SYNCHRONOUS`, respectively.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import Queue
import threading
import time

QUEUE_SIZE = 2 #buffer size of queue

## Placeholder for your functions and variables
N_files = 10
file_list = ['file %d' % i for i in range(N_files)]

def file_reader(filename):
    time.sleep(.1)
    result = (filename,'processed')
    return result

def in_place_processing(f):
    time.sleep(.2)

def processing_function(f1,f2):
    print f1, f2
    return id(f1) & id(f2)

MODE_SYNCHRONOUS = 0  #file_reader called in main thread synchronously
MODE_THREADS = 1      #file_reader executed in worker thread
MODE_PROCESS = 2      #file_reader executed in child_process
##################################################
## Class to encapsulate multiprocessing objects.
class QueuedFileReader():
    def __init__(self, idlist, mode=MODE_PROCESS):
        self.mode = mode
        self.idlist = idlist
        if mode == MODE_PROCESS:
            self.queue = mp.Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)
            self.process = mp.Process(target=QueuedFileReader.worker,
                                      args=(self.queue,idlist))
            self.process.start()
        elif mode == MODE_THREADS:
            self.queue = Queue.Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=QueuedFileReader.worker,
                                           args=(self.queue,idlist))
            self.thread.start()

    @staticmethod
    def worker(queue, idlist):
        for i in idlist:
            queue.put((i, file_reader(file_list[i])))
            print id(queue), 'queued', file_list[i]
        queue.put('done')

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.mode == MODE_SYNCHRONOUS:
            self.index = 0
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.mode == MODE_SYNCHRONOUS:
            if self.index == len(self.idlist): raise StopIteration
            q = (self.idlist[self.index],
                 file_reader(file_list[self.idlist[self.index]]))
            self.index += 1
        else:
            q = self.queue.get()
            if q == 'done': raise StopIteration
        return q

    def __del__(self):
        if self.mode == MODE_PROCESS:
            self.process.join()
        elif self.mode == MODE_THREADS:
            self.thread.join()

#mode = MODE_PROCESS
mode = MODE_THREADS
#mode = MODE_SYNCHRONOUS
result = 0
for i, f1 in QueuedFileReader(range(N_files),mode):

    in_place_processing(f1)

    for j, f2 in QueuedFileReader(range(i+1,N_files),mode):
        in_place_processing(f2)
        result += processing_function(f1,f2)
```

If your intermediate values are too large to pass through the Queue, you can execute each iteration of the outer loop in its own process.  A handy way to do that would be using the `Pool` class in `multiprocessing` as in the example below.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

## Placeholder for your functions and variables
N_files = 10
file_list = ['file %d' % i for i in range(N_files)]

def file_reader(filename):
    time.sleep(.1)
    result = (filename,'processed')
    return result

def in_place_processing(f):
    time.sleep(.2)

def processing_function(f1,f2):
    print f1, f2
    return id(f1) & id(f2)

def file_task(file_index):
    print file_index
    f1 = file_reader(file_list[file_index])
    in_place_processing(f1)
    task_result = 0
    for j in range(file_index+1, N_files):
        f2 = file_reader(file_list[j])
        in_place_processing(f2)
        task_result += processing_function(f1,f2)
    return task_result



pool = mp.Pool(processes=None) #processes default to mp.cpu_count()
result = 0
for file_result in pool.map(file_task, range(N_files)):
    result += file_result
print 'result', result

#or simply
#result = sum(pool.map(file_task, range(N_files)))
```

Comment: If this is to be run under Windows, be aware that true multiprocessing doesn't exist. Spawned processes are actually created as threads. Due to Python's Global Thread Lock, threads cannot run simultaneously. As a result, your program may actually run slower than if your did all the reads and processing in just a single thread. it depends on whether the IO or the processing is the bottleneck. If you're running under Linux, this doesn't apply if your CPU has multiple cores.

Comment: Awesome, thank you -- I wasn't appreciating how well using Queues properly handles the problem.  Is there a particular reason you went with multiprocessing?  Does doing all of this with multithreading instead make a difference?

Comment: I wrote the code above to teach myself about the multiprocessing module in Python, as I hadn't used it before.  Reading the documentation, it seems that some OS implementations of Python may struggle passing serialized data larger than 32 MB between processes, which may be a problem given the size of the files you're processing.  So a solution using threads rather than processes may be better.  However, then the GIL comes into play, as sizzzlerz noted in the comment above.  I'll modify the example above so that the QueuedFileReader class can use either threads or processes so you can test it.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the GIL might be coming into play in the threaded version, as the worker process that adds the read-in files to the queue seems to hold up the processing until it's done (i.e. no win vs. just doing it all in order).  the multiprocessing version just seems to hang, so it will take a bit more tweaking to see if it does work better.

Comment: How big is the object returned by `processing_function` in your example?  If its smaller than 32 MB, you could spin off each iteration of the outer loop into its own process.  Check out the `Pool` class in the `multiprocessing` module. I'll append an example of its usage in the answer above.

Comment: Fixed an off by 1 error in the inner loop my Pool example above.

Comment: The problem I'm still seeing no matter how I do this is that the loading of the queue (which itself works fine in multithreading) doesn't seem to operate in parallel with anything else.  It loads up to the queue limit's worth of files, then passes back the first one . . .